# Can Windows file explorer open a TortoiseSVN URL?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

Is it possible in `C#` to open SVN url such as `http:\\svn.au\svn\type\` in the Windows File Explorer?

I've tried using `OpenFileDialog` with the given path, which gave the error `Unknown Path`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, its true i can start with Process.Start(), in my case i want to get selected file name as string by programmatically using C#, Process.Start() does not help.

Comment: (1) Is that the URL of an SVN server? (2) What do you want to happen? The Explorer is not there to open repositories, but since Tortoise plugs into it, it gives you context menu entries to do SVN-related things. Do you want to start a Tortoise dialogue related to the given URL, e.g. the repository browser, or the log or checkout dialogue? In that case, study [Automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) in the manual.

Comment: @Kumar, you can programmicaly invoke the svn-cli with **1.** checkout to a local directory; **2.** open windows file explorer focused on this directory.  would this kind of solution is relevant to you?

Comment: Thanks PJTraill, and Jossef Harush for reply. i got some info. from both of you. @ PJTraill: its a URL, i want specific Initial SVN folder and files want to Bind to a TreeView WPF and i want FullPath of selectedItem Node. this is firstly to do program in C#.  @Jossef Harush : urs also good idea ,firstly i want to try get folder and files programatically

Comment: You now seem to be saying that you want to walk through files in the repository programmatically, which is miles away from displaying them in Tortoise or the Windows Explorer. Are you trying to write a GUI Subversion client? In that case you need to read up on Subversion API’s, of which I know nothing. (_Warning: please be gentle with your users: I have just read that WPF produces ‘stunning user experiences’._)

Comment: Thank you PJTrail for information , i will look into Subversion API.